# Does linux support multi-touch screen

Tags: linux, multi-touch

I'd like to develop my own app based on a arm-linux system, using QT.
I'd like my app to support multi-touch functions. And I'd like to know if it is possible. If so ,please let me know which version of Linux kernel I should use.

Answer (score 5):

Linux started supporting Microsoft's Multi-touch protocol from kernel 3.8 onwards. 
The reference is here:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/multi-touch-protocol.txt

## Addendum

http://www.ptrackapp.com/apclassys-notes/embedded-linux-multitouch/

has arm multi-touch tutorial for iPhones but it applies equally to Android.

The hid-multitouch in linux supports a whole bunch of panels:

See

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/hid/hid-multitouch.c

for details

## Addendum 2

Multi touch support has been somewhat there since 2.6 Ubuntu had multi touch support in its distribution in 2010.

Microsoft Multi-touch protocol support started in 3.8. Chrome OS support started in kernel v3.9. X.org server had multi touch support built into it in 2011.

Comment: Where can I find the kernel versions that support multi-touch?

Comment: I just told you that linux kernel version 3.8 and onwards support multi-touch functionality.

Comment: **+multitouch +linux** now lands here!

Answer (score -3):

Run command:

```
chromium --enable-pinch
```

for context menu

create shortcut application (.desktop)

```
/home/"your user"/.local/share/applications
```

OR

support all aplications

search:

multi touch compiz plugin

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rY-85BUqWgY